# image and alert do not show up on mobile device

Tags: javascript, html, css

The image(of the body background) and alert(window.alert(s_list[1]);) do not show up on mobile device, although they  show up on regular browser(pc). I tried chrome and google on my device to no avail. I do not know the reason behind this. Please help, thank in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang ="en">
<head>
<style type ="text/css">
.container{
font-size: 40px;

color: blue;

border-radius: 50px

}
.button{
background-color: blue;
color: orange;
min-height: 40px;
min-width: 130px;


}
h3{
color: red;
}
</style>
<script type ="text/javascript">
function myarray () {
var s_list = new Array(3);
s_list[0] = "beginner";
s_list[1] = "intermediate";
s_list[2] = "advanced";
s_list[3] = "professional";
window.alert(s_list[1]);
}

</script>

<title>Choose Level</title>
</head>
<h3> Choose your level then tab Click me!</h3>

<body background ="./images/sea.jpg">

<label class = "container"> 
<input type ="radio" name="radio" checked> Beginner
<span class ="check"></span>
</label>
<br>

<label class ="container"> 
<input type ="radio" name ="radio" checked> Intermediate
<span class ="check"</span>
</label>
<br>
<label class ="container"> 
<input type = "radio" name ="radio" checked> Advanced
<span class ="check"></span>

<br>
<br>
<input type ="button" class ="button" value ="click me!" onclick ="myarray()"></button>

</body>
`</html>
```

Comment: There are multiple mistakes in your html.  The h3 tag should be inside the body tag.  There is a span tag missing a bracket.  There's a button closing tag after an input.  The DOCTYPE is unspecified. You should ensure your html is valid before doing any testing.

Answer (score 0):

The `background=""` attribute is deprecated, instead use this:

```html
<body style="background:url('./images/sea.jpg')">
```

You should also not be using `window.alert()`, instead just use `alert()`.

Here is the fully updated HTML. I also fixed most of the issues inside of the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <style type="text/css">
      .container {
        font-size: 40px;

        color: blue;

        border-radius: 50px;
      }
      .button {
        background-color: blue;
        color: orange;
        min-height: 40px;
        min-width: 130px;
      }
      h3 {
        color: red;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function myarray() {
        var s_list = new Array(3);
        s_list[0] = "beginner";
        s_list[1] = "intermediate";
        s_list[2] = "advanced";
        s_list[3] = "professional";
        alert(s_list[1]);
      }
    </script>

    <title>Choose Level</title>
  </head>
  <h3>Choose your level then tab Click me!</h3>

  <body style="background:url('./images/sea.jpg')">
    <label class="container">
      <input type="radio" name="radio" checked /> Beginner
      <span class="check"></span>
    </label>
    <br />

    <label class="container">
      <input type="radio" name="radio" checked /> Intermediate
      <span class="check"></span>
    </label>
    <br />
    <label class="container">
      <input type="radio" name="radio" checked /> Advanced
      <span class="check"></span>
    </label>

    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="button" class="button" value="click me!" onclick="myarray()" />
  </body>
  `
</html>
```